# Lost Unity panel - how to recover it?

Tags: panel

I've installed 11.04 but some windows effects were off, so I tried to re-enable them. While in the process, however, I ended up losing that handy menu (normally on top) where we have the Ubuntu icon, and the volume and shutdown menus.

How can we restore that panel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
unity --reset
```

All it will be recovered.

Credits go to ubuntuforums. :)

Comment: It would've been nice if you left a link to the forum post which provided your answer.