# Missing panel on my second monitor, any fix?

Tags: panel

I've turned on my computer to awaken to no top bar on my second monitor. However, it was there before I shutdown the day before.

I don't remember touching anything to do with my monitors and would like to know if there is a fix for this?

I would really like it back :)

Comment: Strange; I restarted (Even thou i did that plenty of times before) and It's now back.Sorry! :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have resolved your own question, please properly mark it as fixed by posting an answer below and clicking the checkmark icon after the appropriate time period has elapsed. This indicates to the system and other users that your question has been solved. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/37834/18612

Comment: I would consider this a distinct question, the unwanted behaviour only happens on the second monitor.

Comment: @Flimm To the extent to which this is a separate issue, it's too localized, unless the problem has returned.